# Neural Network for bit operation AND

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

This is probably not the best place to ask this question but I am really struggling. 
I want to create a "trivial" neural network which has 2 inputs, 3 hidden neurons and 1 output. The idea is that we feed it two booleans and it outputs the AND result.

I wanted to do it in a somewhat "conventional" way (I am still very new to pytorch). I'm using the Adam optimiser with a learning rate of 0.001 and the nll_loss function (although I need to change it as I need to have only 1 output and this requires the number of outputs to match the number of classes - in this case 1 and 0)

I know this should be a really trivial problem but I am really struggling and can't find anything useful on google.

Comment: There are other communities on the [stackexchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites) sites.  With SO the biggest. But among them is the smaller [AI](https://ai.stackexchange.com/) community.  I have a hunch that you'll find some people there that share your field of expertise.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the AND result? So you mean if you pass it True, True it returns True, but if you pass it True False or False True it returns False?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a `.csv` file with your training data.

```
x1  x2  label
TRUE    FALSE   FALSE
TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
FALSE   TRUE    FALSE
```

Create a dataset class.

```
class boolData(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, csv_path):
        self.label = pd.read_csv(csv_path)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.label)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        sample = torch.tensor(self.label.iloc[idx,0:2]).int()
        label = torch.tensor(self.label.iloc[idx,2]).int()
        return sample, label

tensor_dataset = boolData(csv_path='sample_bool_stack.csv')

boolDL = DataLoader(tensor_dataset, batch_size=4, shuffle=True)

batch, labels = next(iter(boolDL))

batch, labels
```

```
(tensor([[1, 0],
         [1, 1],
         [0, 1],
         [0, 0]], dtype=torch.int32), tensor([0, 1, 0, 0], dtype=torch.int32))
```

Initialize embeddings.

```
def _emb_init(x):
    x = x.weight.data
    sc = 2/(x.size(1)+1)
    x.uniform_(-sc,sc)
```

The model converts `True`, `False` to integers and takes the sum as the input.
EDIT: output with just single neuron.

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.emb = nn.Embedding(3, 2)
        _emb_init(self.emb)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(2, 10)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(10, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.sum(x, dim=1)
        x = self.emb(x)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x
```

Initialize model, optimizer, and loss function. EDIT: change loss to match single neuron output.

```
model = Net()
opt = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
loss_func = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
num_epochs = 10000

device = "cpu"
```

Train model.

```
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for i,(inputs, labels) in enumerate(boolDL):
        inputs = inputs.to(device).long()
        labels = labels.to(device).float()

        opt.zero_grad()

        output = model(inputs)
        loss = loss_func(output.view(-1), labels)
        loss.backward()
        opt.step()
        with torch.no_grad():
            if epoch % 2000 == 0: print(loss.item())
```

```
0.004416308831423521
0.002891995944082737
0.004371378570795059
0.0017852336168289185
```

Test model.

```
inputs = torch.tensor([[0,0],[0,1],[0,0]])

def check_model(inputs):
    out = model(inputs)
    preds = torch.sigmoid(out).round()
    return preds.detach().numpy()

check_model(inputs)
```

```
array([[0.],
       [0.],
       [0.]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: You are nuts, thank you so much. I just have two questions: First, can we do this with just one output neuron? Second, if I test the model with just one sample aka: `model(torch.tensor[[1,1]])` it always returns [0,0]. Why does it work when testing with batches of 4 but not 1?

Comment: @Mitch I edited my answer to use single neuron output. I tested with different length inputs and it seems to work.